# how to get values from tuple key in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have:

```
py_dict = {("z",): 5, 
        ("a", "b", "c", "d"): 1,
        ("q", "w", "e", "r"): 2
        }
```

and i need to access the values i.e, 1 and 2, 5

output should be:

```
if i got z then I should be 5
if i got any alphabets from a, b, c, d then I should get 1
if i got any alphabets from q, w, e, r then I should get 2
```

Comment: you meant to put your z in quotes, didn't you?

Comment: It's going to be very inefficient to search through all of the keys, you'd be better flattening it to `{'z': 5, 'a': 1, 'b': 1, ...}`.

Comment: you will probably want to iterate through your dict: `for key,val in py_dict.items():`
and in the loop: `if mychar in key: return val`  or something like that.  But @jonrsharpe has the better idea.  It also avoids having a character in multiple keys.

Answer (score 1):

The current format of your dictionary doesn't lend itself to efficient lookups of individual letters. Consider reformatting it so that every key is just a single letter.

```py
>>> new_dict = {key2: py_dict[key1] for key1 in py_dict for key2 in key1}
>>> new_dict
{'z': 5, 'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 1, 'q': 2, 'w': 2, 'e': 2, 'r': 2}
>>> new_dict['a']
1
```

If you have requirements that you keep the existing format then you'll have to iterate through each key and check for membership:

```py
>>> for key, val in py_dict.items():
        if 'a' in key:
            print(val)
            break
1
```